# Get list of components in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have to get the components in Vue 2:
i the main page i have this:

```
import { component1, component2, component3, } from '@/components'
export default {
  components: {
    component1,
    component2,
    component3
  }
}
```

How I can do something like that:

```
methods: {
  getComponents () {
    return this.$components
  }
}
```

Comment: What about ```Object.keys(components)``` in a computed method for example ? Maybe you can also do this: ```this.$options.components```

Comment: What is the purpose? Could be XY problem